# Can we say that events A and B are dependent if $A=B\neq S$?

Tags: probability

Note that S is the sample space. We have $P(A|B)=P(A|A)=1\neq P(A)$. By definition A and B are dependent. But I am not sure the definition can be applied in this case. I also want to know what if $A=\varnothing$. Please help

Comment: What is $S{}{}$?

Comment: $S$ is the sample space

Comment: Pleaseadd that information to the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $A$ and $B$ are independent if $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$.
In the case $A=B$, $A \cap B = A$ so this says $P(A) = P(A)^2$, and that is true if and only if $P(A)$ is either $0$ or $1$.  In particular,  $ \emptyset$ and $\emptyset$ are independent, as are $S$ and $S$. If $0 < P(A) < 1$, then $A$ and $A$ are dependent.

Comment: Do we prefer the condition of independence $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$ to $P(A|B)=P(A)$? Since when $P(B)=0$, $P(A|B)$ is not defined.

Comment: That's indeed the main reason why $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$ is the preferred condition.